# What is the difference between "fetched URL" and "canonical URL" in Facebook's Sharing Debugger?

Tags: facebook, url, facebook-opengraph, facebook-debugger

I was using the Facebook's Sharing Debugger tool, and I have a question. What exactly is the difference between the '***fetched URL** (URL buscada)*' and the '***canonical URL** (URL canônica)*'?

[Print from Facebook's Sharing Debugger](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jmY6V.png)

I've been reading some explanations about this, but I still don't quite understand how it works. Could someone help me understand the difference and how does it work?

Sorry for the dumb question, I'm still learning. Thanks in advance!

Comment: canonical URL will be the final URL if there are redirects.

Comment: The purpose of a canonical URL itself is described here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonical_link_element When it comes to determining what should be considered the “real” URL of a piece of shared content, Facebook prioritizes the `og:url`, if explicitly specified, and otherwise the canonical URL next. If neither are specified, then the input URL (after any redirect that might happen) is used.